# Complex - Testing Convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{2}z^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Just wanting to make sure my conclusions are correct for this

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{2}z^{n}\quad \text{for}\quad |z| < 1 $$

When using the ratio and root test, i conclude that my series has either divergence or convergence. Totally not cool right?

So I then and use Dirichlet Test
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Letting $a_n = n^{2}$ and $b_n = z^{2}$, its obvious that the function fails the first two tests.

So will it then diverge?

Comment: If $|z|<1$, both the Ratio Test and the Root Test conclusively show that the series converges.

Comment: We like to help but there is some turbulence on this website!  Whenever I post they just downvote which is an immature act!

Comment: And actually, for $\sum_{n\geq0} P(n)z^n$, where $P$ is a polynomial or a rational fraction (with nonvanishing denominator for integer $n$), the radius of convergence is always $1$, by the above test.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal : Change your name on the website. Nothing is disturbed by doing that, except that someone targeting you may not know who you are any more. :)

Comment: @TrialAndError One has to change the account then. Changing the printed name won't help, since it's possible to find the account with only the user number (try [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/35472/)), and it would be also possible to check an old question with an answer from the same person, where the name would be apparent. I fear the only solution is to start from scratch, which is rather annoying.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut : Most people who are abusive don't spend a lot of time checking things, unless they're really out to get you. And they won't have cause to check because they'll probably never revisit an old answer. And abusive types are not typically hard-working; if they were then they would not have to be abusive to get somewhere in life. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio test:
$$
   1 >  \lim_{n}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}|z| =|z| .
$$
The root test:
$$
   1 > \lim_{n}(n^2|z|^{n})^{1/n} = \lim_{n}e^{2\frac{ln(n)}{n}}|z|=|z|.
$$
In either case, you have absolute convergence for $|z| < 1$ and divergence for $|z| > 1$.